# Slickgrid: Checkboxs + Pagination: getSelectedRows for all pages, and not only the current one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slickgrid

I got a grid, with checkboxes plugin and Pagination.

I can get selected rows only for the current page I'm at, but not of all the rows. How one can do that?

I search the code, tried finding the global array slickgrid is taking the selected rows when it enters a new page (`dataView.syncGridSelection(grid, true)`), but didn't manage doing so till now...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `onPagingInfoChanged` event - which gets triggered when you navigate to a new page - then store the selected rows from that page into a global array for your reference.

```
dataView.onPagingInfoChanged.subscribe(function(e,pagingInfo) {
  console.log(grid.getSelectedRows());
  // add selected rows to a global array
}
```

Note: further to what you mentioned, the `grid.getSelectedRows()` returns the row number **relative to the visible rows**. So rows on page 2 will start with 0. I would advise to instead get the `id` of the row and store that in the global array instead (you know, the one each row in the dataview should have and which is unique).

Hope this gives you a start. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thats exactly what I did. I am listening to onSelectedRowsChanged event, and populating a global array from there. Thanks for your answer & help. I do think that this behaviour needs to enter the fw. Developers do need to hold in hand the global list, in order to run bulk operations.

Comment: The reason I'm checking on every checkbox click, is to enable or disable a bulk operation button. User can always deselect all checkboxs before switching a page.

Comment: You are most welcome! SlickGrid by design is meant to keep only visible rows in memory - I think this is what makes it so fast. I think that's the reason it was implemented this way. Fun to play around though - and we do have workarounds for our special needs! :)